# ATI Radeon X1200 Series(RS690M) graphical drivers problem

Tags: unity, 11.10, ati

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [open source ATI drivers not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91648/open-source-ati-drivers-not-working)

In the brand new Ubuntu 11.10 the drivers of ATI Radeon X1200 Series(RS690M) seems to be broken. Even when moving single window, it's barely moving. The drivers in 11.04 were working very well till the upgrade. When we can expect the thins working back again?

Comment: did u fix it? I have the same issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/91648/open-source-ati-drivers-not-working

Comment: An answer has been accepted at @Stann's question - [Open Source ATI drivers not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91648/open-source-ati-drivers-not-working). Hence voting to close this off as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same problem with my Toshiba Equium P200D which has the RS690 radeon X1200 chipset and I now have the standard radeon driver to working, 3D and everything no problems.

To fix this I played with the radeon driver settings by adding the `radeon-kms.conf` file to the `/etc/modprobe.d` directory. Simply create the aforementioned file with the following entries:

```
options radeon noaccel=0
options radeon exavsync=0
options radeon colortiling=1
options radeon exapixmaps=1
options radeon enablepageflip=1
```

Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: This caused errors with loading the radeon kernal module. (RS690M on a eMachines D620 laptop running 10.10).  It did give me a clue.  I ended up adding similar lines to xorg.conf and driconf (see answer).  Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been pursuing this problem while running 10.10 on an eMachine D620 (x1250, RS690M chipset).  I am using the radeon drivers from xorg-edgers-radeon ppa (http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/radeon/ubuntu).

Starting with Thomas's work, I was able to find a mostly working solution.  The key enabler seems to be vsync_mode.

The first test that worked was running glxgears using the command line `vsync_mode=0 glxgears`.  The result was going from ~10 FPS to ~150 FPS.  (This is still not great, but a huge change.)  To make this change permanent, I then ran driconf and set the option "Synchronize with vertical refresh" to "Never synchronize...".  Logging out and back in made this take effect and solve 90% of my problems.

I have also applied changes from Thomas Wake into my /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.  Here is what it looks like now

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
        Driver   "radeon"
        Option  "DRI" "on"              #on is the default in recent radeonhd versions
        Option  "AccelMethod" "EXA"     #this is the default in recent radeonhd versions
#!used  Option  "EAXVSync"      "off"
        Option  "ColorTiling"   "on"
#!used  Option  "AGPMode"       "8"
#!used  Option  "AGPFastWrites" "on"
        Option  "EXAPixmaps"    "on"
        Option  "AccelDFS"      "on"
        Option  "RenderAccel"   "on"
#!used  Option  "DRI2"          "on"
        # from another source
        Option  "NoAccel"       "off"
#!used  Option  "EnablePageFlips"       "on"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen" 
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "CYonfigured Video Device"
EndSection
```

The lines starting `#!used` are options that are not used, but recommended by others from previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

yes, indeed. video hardware is not recognized by the latest catalyst that works with 11.10 and non-proprietary driver doesn't have a lot of features + because of video hang, computer don't resume from sleep

Comment: so - what can we do?