# open source ATI drivers not working

Tags: drivers, ati

Default Ubuntu 10.10 install.

system info -> graphics -> driver says "unknown" and experiece : 'standard'
Hardware -> additional drivers : totally empty.
Windows are moving around sorta slow.
lspci | grep VGA

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RS690M [Radeon X1200 Series]
```

What's wrong. Why doesn't additional drivers show propertietary ATI driver? And why is there driver : "unknown"

Can somebody help me to troubleshoot this one...

Comment: Speed up unity http://askubuntu.com/questions/39050/how-can-i-speed-up-unity-in-ubuntu-11-04-natty/39976#39976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find your driver here:
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Once you download it, install it:

```
sudo sh 'path/to/file/drivers.sh'
```

After it is done installing, type into terminal:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

Then restart and it should work!

Comment: em. i get that diver is in legacy group or somthting...http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Legacy/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.7&product=2.7.2.3.2&lang=English

Comment: There is a download link at the bottom of that page...

Comment: hmm. i see. not sure why open source driver didn't work - but proprietary worked fine. thanks.